# How can I see all applications I gave security permissions in the past?

Tags: security, permission, ventura

MacOS Venture: 13

I am going through my Mac right now, cleaning it up doing some general security checks and what not. Throughout the years I've downloaded many applications, software, libraries etc needed for my development and some of them require additional permissions in the security tab in the settings.

System Settings > Privacy And Security > Security > Allow app...

Im not sure exactly what its called, but for example when I downloaded Virtual box before running it(At least version <6...) I had to go into Security and click allow under Virtualbox.

Now is there a way for me to view all the times I have done this ^ so I can end up revoking any permissions on old applications/applications no longer needed?

If it matters, I have been doing this since at least MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

> Im not sure exactly what its called, but for example when I downloaded
> Virtual box before running it(At least version <6...) I had to go into
> Security and click allow under Virtualbox.

That's not the usual practice for applications: it sounds like the process for allowing system extensions, which in Ventura are now disabled by default.

Otherwise, when you download an application, you might be asked to allow it on the first launch, if it's not from an 'identified' developer.

You will also have to grant access for each to access the Documents, Desktop and Downloads folders, as well as network drives.